# Linked CSS buttons don't work in IE11

Tags: css, button, internet-explorer-11, compatibility

I am trying to create a group of buttons that will act as a page navigation for my site (a mobile/desktop hybrid that's the result of a non-mobile friendly platform). These buttons work in Chrome and Safari. When I test in IE11 they do not work. Does anyone know of any compatibility issues with IE11? Source code is below but note that I have commented out the :hover style.

```
<style>
    .button1 { background-color:#17365d; border: 2px solid #17365d; width: 100%; height: 90px; color: white; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; font-size: 20px; cursor: pointer; } //.button1:hover { background-color:#e0e0e0; border: 2px solid #17365d; color: black; -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; }//
</style>
<table style="width: 100%;" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 33.3%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><a href="/hqrio/resources.aspx"><button class="button1" type="button">Resources</button></a></td>
            <td style="width: 33.3%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><a href="/HQRIO/IMATravel.aspx"><button class="button1" type="button">IMA Travel</button></a> </td>
            <td style="width: 33.3%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><a href="/HQRIO/IMA-RPO.aspx"><button class="button1" type="button">Military Pay</button></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 33.3%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><a href="/HQRIO/Education-Force-Development.aspx"><button class="button1" type="button">Education &amp; Force Development</button></a></td>
            <td style="width: 33.3%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><a href="/HQRIO/Benefits.aspx"><button class="button1" type="button">Entitlements &amp; Benefits</button></a></td>
            <td style="width: 33.3%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><a href="/HQRIO/IMAVacancies.aspx"><button class="button1" type="button">IMA Vacancies</button></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 33.3%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><a href="/HQRIO/Detachments.aspx"><button class="button1" type="button">HQ RIO Detachments</button></a></td>
            <td style="width: 33.3%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><a href="/HQRIO/awards-boards.aspx"><button class="button1" type="button">Awards &amp; Boards </button></a></td>
            <td style="width: 33.3%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><a href="/HQRIO/training.aspx"><button class="button1" type="button">Training </button></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually add a Javascript event that changed pages on the divs themselves instead of adding a button. This should work on IE11 too, and possibly even on older versions of Internet Explorer. I think I remember doing such things on codecademy...

Of course this requires you know javascript and my own knowledge is too rusty (if it wasn't, I'd have added some code myself)